# How can I specify a package version for bio conductor package in Travis?

Tags: r, travis-ci, bioconductor, rhdf5

I am trying to use travis for my R package.

The check are fine for R 3.4, results are [here](https://travis-ci.org/rte-antares-rpackage/antaresProcessing/jobs/346820435)

For R 3.3, Travis is KO because Travis install the package rhdf5 but it's not the correct version. Results are [here](https://travis-ci.org/rte-antares-rpackage/antaresProcessing/jobs/346820437#L1158)

I have in my description file, the following lines

```
Imports:
data.table,
methods,
stats
Suggests:
rhdf5 (>= 2.20.0),
parallel,
testthat,
knitr,
rmarkdown,
covr
```

For R 3.4, travis does this

```
Installing R packages: rhdf5, zlibbioc
108.31s$ Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("rhdf5", "zlibbioc"));if   (!all(c("rhdf5", "zlibbioc") %in% installed.packages())) { q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
Installing packages into ‘/home/travis/R/Library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.6/bioc/src/contrib  /rhdf5_2.22.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5475293 bytes (5.2 MB)
```

For R 3.3, travis does this

```
Installing R packages: rhdf5, zlibbioc
7.09s$ Rscript -e 'install.packages(c("rhdf5", "zlibbioc"));if   (!all(c("rhdf5", "zlibbioc") %in% installed.packages())) { q(status = 1, save = "no")}'
Installing packages into ‘/Users/travis/R/Library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://bioconductor.org/packages/3.4/bioc/bin/macosx/mavericks /contrib/3.3/rhdf5_2.18.0.tgz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1557714 bytes (1.5 MB)
```

So for R 3.3, Travis install rhdf5 2.18 but in my description file I specified 2.20.

Result of the check for R 3.3

```
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Package required and available but unsuitable version: ‘rhdf5’
```

How to tell to Travis to install rhdf5 but only if the version 2.20 is available ?

I didn't find this information in the travis Doc [here](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/r/)

Must I set _R_CHECK_FORCE_SUGGESTS to FALSE ?

Currently this is my yaml file

```
language: R
sudo: true
cache: packages


bioc_required: true
bioc_use_devel: true

os:
 - linux
 - osx

r:
 - oldrel
 - release
 - devel


r_github_packages:
 - hadley/devtools#1263
 - rte-antares-rpackage/antares-rpackageRead@develop
#before - Bioconductor-mirror/zlibbioc
# - Bioconductor-mirror/rhdf5
#after
bioc_packages:
  - rhdf5
  - zlibbioc


r_packages:
  - covr
  - devtools
  - data.table
  - lubridate
  - plyr
  - stringr
  - shiny
  - knitr
  - testthat
  - rmarkdown

after_success:
  - Rscript -e 'library(covr); codecov()'
```